# Unknown chunk in Mac png screenshots

Tags: macos, png

Right after the IHDR chunk in Mac screenshots there is a segment that starts with 'QiCCPICC Profile'. The first bytes of this section appear to be 00,00,18,51 (51 is the 'Q') in hex, which does not appear to follow the specification that the first 4 bytes of a chunk represent its length. This section precedes the IDAT chunk.

My question is, what is the purpose of this large chunk? What is the background behind why it is there?
Below is a sample mac screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I think your counting is off by a byte, and you are looking at an `iCCP` chunk with ICC Profile. Try running a screen-grab through `pngcheck -vv YourGrab.png`

Comment: You are correct. Checked using pngcheck and it is an ICCP chunk. thanks